# Initialize the counter for every loop

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to initialize a counter for every loop:

```
 for i in range(10):
    print i
    for j in range(10):
        print j
        i = 0
```

Above is my code, but I doesn't work. Can any one help me with it?

Comment: Define "doesn't work"?

Comment: @vaultah the i won't be set to 0 after each j loop.

Comment: Of course `i` is set to 0. But after the second loop is done, `next` is called on the listiterator the first `range` produces and the name `i` is assigned to the return value.

Answer (score 1):

You can't modify the iterator of a loop and then have those modifications carry on to the next iteration (for the reasons @timgeb stated above). However, if you want to only increase an iterator if certain conditions are met after a series of operations, this is what `while` statements are for :

```
i=0
while True:
    print("i is %i" % i)
    for j in range(10):
        if j in (2, 3):
            print("j is %i" % j)
        elif j in (5,6):
            i +=1
        else:
           pass 
    if i==12:
        break
```

In this case, we increase i only if certain conditions are met and then break out of the loop when we have completed the desired number of iterations.

Answer (score -1):

this may be what you are looking for

```
for i in range(1,11):
    print(i)
    for j in range(1,11):
        if j != 10:
            print(j, end=" ")
        else:
            print(j)
```

It prints out the loop number, then prints out 1 through 10, in increasing order